# Find all numbers $p$ so that $f$ is continuous on $(- ∞, ∞)$

Tags: calculus

$$
F(x)= \begin{cases}px^2& x\leq2\\
      2x+p& x>2\end{cases}
$$

I'm confused how to set up this problem.. can anyone help get me started?

Comment: There's only one possible point of discontinuity.  Make sure the graph approaches the same value from both sides of this potential jump discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

A function is continuous on $(a,b)$ if for all points in $(a,b)$, $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. Hence, find $p$ so that ($f$ is continuous everywhere, but is possibly discontinuous at $x=2$ - let's check):
$$\lim_{x\to 2}(2x+p)=\lim_{x\to 2}(px^2)\\
\implies 4+p=4p\\
\implies p=\dfrac{4}{3}$$

Comment: Typo in the sign ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The only place where the function can't be continuous is at $x=2$ because it's a piece wise function. In order for it to be continuous, both parts must have the same value at $x=2$:
$$px^2=2x+p \; \text{(at x=2)}$$
$$p(2)^2=2(2)+p \Rightarrow 4p=4+p$$
$$\therefore p=\frac43$$